# Sending Azure Blob Storage csv file as an attachment to user on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, email-attachments, azure-logic-apps, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-blob-storage

I have created a Logic App in Microsoft Azure. I am having a scheduler recurrence first and then I am calling Azure ML Batch Job with Job Input and Output.  After this now, I have to send email to the user with azure blob storage .csv file generated in Azure after running Azure ML job. So, how can I send the azure blob storage file to user after running Azure ML Batch Job with Job Input and Output?

Comment: Thanks for the reply George. This is helpful and will try to implement this.

Answer (score 3):

From your description, I assume you just don't know hoe to add the attachment in Send an email action. Here is the Logic Apps flow.

You should in the `Send an email action` tick `Attachments` under `Add new parameter`,then you will be able to add attachments.  If in the Dynamic content there is not `File Content` there, you could go to `code view`, and edit the `Send_an_email` action there, the `ContentBytes` under `Attachments` should be `@{base64(body('Get_blob_content'))}`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

And here is the test mail result. The csv file content is right.

[image]

Comment: @Aditya Kumar, if this don't work, please let me know, if worked you could mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi , I am trying to monitor a newly added blob, and pass this to the new file and send by mail. What would it look like ?